# GCP - Can we enforce a user to add labels while creating resources?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to enforce the addition of labels while creating resources? If not, is there a way to automatically label resources when creating said resources in GCP?

My use case: I need this to investigate the price in Data Studio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't enforce any one to put labels on resources on GCP (same for projects). **BUT** you can enforce [TAG](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-overview#inheritance) automatically by inheritance. (You can't oblige a user to use them, but, by default there is a tag).

The TAG are still in preview and were named "label next gen" during the Alpha period. So, you can use them like labels, but you can enforce authorization on them (who can up view/update/delete them). This feature is very interesting because today, anyone with admin/owner roles can update/change/delete labels and you lost the control and the monitoring of your resources.

You can also put IAM condition on them and enforce organization policies accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't enforce users to do so. However you can:

- Create a log sink if a resource is created
- Use that log sink to call a cloud function that will create an alert or give a default label
- If you use infrastructure as code for example Terraform, you can put a CI/CD job that will check if a label is placed, and if not reject the PR.